# ActiveMQ Artemis: Can slave instance be a connection point for the clients?

Tags: jms, activemq-artemis

The ActiveMQ Artemis documentation says:

> Slave will be in passive mode until the master crashes...

That's OK, but it's not clear if brokers in passive mode can be a connection point. In other words, can I put my slave in the connection list for a remote client like below?

```
(tcp://my-master:61616,tcp://my-slave:61616)?reconnectAttempts=5
```

If yes, does it means that a broker in passive mode is just a router?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ActiveMQ Artemis JMS client supports a list of servers to be used for the initial connection attempt. It can be specified in the connection URI using a syntax with (), e.g.: `(tcp://myhost:61616,tcp://myhost2:61616)?reconnectAttempts=5`. The client uses this list of servers to create the first connection.

The slave broker doesn't accept incoming client connections until it becomes live, but it is important to include both the master and the slave uri in the list because the client can't know who is live when it creates the initial connection.